# Can't get categories on Likes on new FB graph API (2.5)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am using this URL to access facebook likes off of an authorized and logged in user:

**https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/likes?access_token=accessToken**

it returns this

```
"data": [
      {
         "name": "Page Name",
         "category": "Category name",
         "id": "12345678",
         "created_time": "2012-03-26T08:02:01+0000"
      },
```

However on my new app which uses API 2.5

**https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/likes?access_token=accessToken**

it returns this

```
"data": [
      {
         "name": "Page Name",
         "id": "12345678",
         "created_time": "2012-03-26T08:02:01+0000"
      },
```

Which is minus the category name.
I have my new app registered in FB and it will not allow me change API from 2.5, and even on my new app if I use the 2.3 URL it will **still** not display categories.

Does anyone know what extra calls I need to make to get categories or why they have disapeared in newer versions of the API, I can't find anything on google or on FB's doco's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s called "Declarative Fields", check out the changelog for v2.4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

That´s what you need to change:

```
/me/likes?fields=name,category&access_token=accessToken
```